# Evaluate $ \lim\limits_{x\to 1} \frac{(\ln x)^2}{1-x} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have trouble finding the limit of the following :
$$ \lim\limits_{x\to 1} \frac{(\ln x)^2}{1-x} $$
using the rule from L´Hopital.

Since both quotients converge to $0$, I should be able to use L´Hopitals´s rule right?

But when I do that the derivations converge to $$\frac{0}{-1}$$
Does that mean that there's no limit?

Comment: No it doesn't. It means just that: the limit is $\frac{0}{-1}=0$

Comment: So it just means that it converges to $0$ ? thats it ?

Comment: Yep, that's it.

Comment: It's spelled "L'Hopital."

Comment: @fluffy my bad, changed it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using l'Hopital's rule, we find $$ \lim_{x \to 1} \frac {\ln^2 x}{1-x} = \lim_{x \to 1} \frac {2 \ln x \cdot \frac {1}{x}}{-1} = \lim_{x \to 1} - \frac {2 \ln x}{x} = \lim_{x \to 1} 0 = \boxed {0}. $$We know l'Hopital's rule applies because it is of the form $ \frac {\ln^2 1}{1-1} = \frac {0}{0} $, which is indeed indeterminate.

Comment: But $2ln(x)\cdot\frac{1}{x}$ converges to $0$ no?
So you have $\frac{0}{-1}$ and that is $0$. That´s at least how i got it. Maybe I´m wrong ...

Comment: @DavidMitra Yes, you are right. I made a mistake, but I've fixed it. Were you the one who downvoted? If so, I suggest you revert. :)

Comment: @ViktorG Did you downvote? I suggest you revert now. :)

Comment: No it wasn´t me :/ I think I dont even have enough rep

Comment: No, I didn't downvote.

Comment: @ViktorG Thanks for the accept! :)

Answer (score 4):

We can use approximations : $\ln(x) \approx x-1$ when $x$ is close to $1$. Hence the required limit reduces to $\lim_{x \to 1}(1-x)=0$

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps
$$ \lim\limits_{x\to 1} \frac{(\ln x)^2}{1-x} = \lim\limits_{x\to 1} \frac{\frac{d}{dx}(\ln x)^2}{\frac{d}{dx}[1-x]} $$
$$ =\lim\limits_{x\to 1} \frac{2(\ln x)\frac{d}{dx}[\ln x]}{\frac{d}{dx}[1]-\frac{d}{dx}[x]} =2\lim\limits_{x\to 1} \frac{\frac{\ln x}{x}}{0-1} $$
$$ =-2\lim\limits_{x\to 1} \frac{\ln x}{x} =-2\left(\frac{0}{1}\right)=-2(0)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

by L'Hospital we get $$\lim_{x \to 1}2\ln(x)\frac{1}{x}(-1)=0$$

Comment: yup got it thank you :)

Comment: It's spelled "L'Hopital."

Comment: i think no, see here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html

Comment: @fluffy It can be either L'Hospital or L'Hôpital. In French, the circumflex [indicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_of_the_circumflex_in_French) that there was a following *s* in a historical spelling.

Comment: @WChargin Ah, thanks, I didn't know that. I'll drop the pet peeve. :)